# Rotational Motion, Kinematics, Air Resistance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, projectile, drag

When a body is thrown of height in a practical situation ( air is present ) considering air resistance is applying constant opposite force,  we could calculate its speed by calculating acceleration and using kinematics equation. But what if we give an angular velocity to the body will its speed remain same as calculated above or change.

Comment: Do you with "*give a angular velocity to the body*" mean that it starts to spin?

Comment: You might find it helpful to look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtP_bh2lMXc